# Save chart as image from dash at start

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have some charts generated through Dash and I would like these charts to be saved at Dash server start.

```
app.layout = html.Div(
                children=[ 
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id='serious-chart',
                        style={
                                "width": '1000px',
                                'height': '500px',
                                }
                    ),
                ],style={'position':'absolute',
                                'width':'160vh',
                                'height':'55vh',
                                'top': '142%',
                                'left': '50%',
                                'border': '1px solid black',
                                'border-radius':'10px',
                                "transform": "translate(-50%, -50%)",
                                }
            )

@app.callback( 
    Output(component_id='serious-chart',component_property='figure'), 
    Input(component_id='input-bar',component_property='value'),
)
def returnCharts(value):
    """ some code here """

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Need some code to save Figure 'serious-chart' as jpeg or Png.

Comment: Did you try `fig.write_image("images/fig1.png")` ? See https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/#write-image-file.

Comment: Or if you want to save an interactive figure use fig.write_html("serious-chart.html")